# AWS SESv2, how to set FROM NAME

Tags: amazon-ses

I could find a solution for `AWS-SES` but there is nothing about `AWS-SESV2`

It used to be `Source: "App Name!! <from_email@example.com>"` but it doesn't seem to work with v2.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question at the same time as scanning through the API v2 Reference docs, so thought the following answer would help

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/API_SendEmail.html

> **FromEmailAddress**
>
> The email address to use as the "From" address for the email. The
> address that you specify has to be verified.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: No

Example...

```
POST /v2/email/outbound-emails HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
   "Content": { 
      "Simple": { 
         "Body": { 
            "Html": { 
               "Charset": "string",
               "Data": "string"
            },
            "Text": { 
               "Charset": "string",
               "Data": "string"
            }
         },
         "Subject": { 
            "Charset": "string",
            "Data": "string"
         }
      }
   },
   "Destination": { 
      "ToAddresses": [ "string" ]
   },
   "FromEmailAddress": "string"   <--- I believe this is what you're looking for
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FromEmailAddress:

```
FromEmailAddress: 'App Name!! <from_email@example.com>'
```

Comment: I just did the migration and guessed that this was the field. But it seems to drop everthing in <> for me in Outlook. When I reply the email is there, but not presented in the email header. Is there an issue tracker for the SDK?

Comment: It does look correct in the Mac Outlook client, so it seems like it was a bug in outlook.com in my case.